# Zookeeper fails to delete nodes (topics in Kafka)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to delete a topic nodes in Zookeeper for Kafka. I tried: rmr /brokers/topics, as well as deleting individual node topics (delete /brokers/topics/topic-1). 
It worked for most topics, but I 4 topics/nodes that just refuse to get deleted.

Any ideas?

Comment: I had partitions where the broker / leader for the partition was down, and it kept the topic from deleting. Is it possible something is preventing an individual broker from deleting its partitions? Like, you only set `delete.topic.enable=true` for one broker? Or not at all?

Comment: I did have some problems with topics not being deleted (that's why I tried to delete them manually), so you are probably on the right track. That said, I deleted all Kafka data, and then stopped the cluster - zookeeper should be able to delete those nodes.

Comment: Also, what version of Kafka?

Comment: and delete.topic.enable=true is set for all brokers.

Comment: confluent 2.0.0, so kafka 0.9.0.0

Comment: Like I said, I only have seen this behavior when one of the brokers couldn't delete its partitions -- maybe check broker logs and see if the some other kind of exception is keeping partitions from being deleted. Wish I had more for you, but there's a reason this is a comment not a full blown answer :)

Comment: So I forgot that I had a producer running, and re-creating these topics..... Still weird, since the topics are listed as "marked for deletion" (even though they have been deleted and re-created)

Comment: Haha that's awesome.